# How to get a variable from a scope two levels above into an isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting a specific variable into the scope of a directive I just created. This variable lives in a scope that is two levels higher (i.e there is another scope in between the one I want to access and the one I just created). My issue is that I have no idea where that intermediary scope comes from, and I have no idea how to pass the variable into the scope unless the variable I want is in the parent scope. I could do it manually like so:

```
$scope.var = $scope.$parent.$parent.var
```

But an issue arises if the variable in the parent parent scope is null. Not to mention all this extra JavaScript would be tedious and unnecessary. For now, I have gotten around this by using setInterval to check if its null every 5 seconds, and make the appropriate assignment if it's not.

How would I go about fixing the structure of scopes so that I can simply use:

```
scope: {
   var: '='
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on a specific need you basically have 4 options:

1) Shared score (if it's your directive, you can set `scope=false`) - then you will be able to directly access variables from paren't directive.

But this won't work if you have to access 2 scopes above and the intermediate scope is not shared.

2) Declare isolated scope `scope = { var: 'var' }`, and explicitly pass the variable from parent scope to your directive tag attributes.

3) Not use scope at all - you can send the variable as part of $broadcast method from parent to child scope and $emit method from child to parent.

4) Inject a service to both parent and child controller and share the variable using this service.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.. On the directive I created, I needed to pass in the variable I needed. For example:

```
<my-directive myVar="var"></my-directive>
```

And in the JavaScrpit:

```
scope: {
   var: 'myVar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make your $scope.var to global variable since parent's scope is shared through its children, which means that you can access to your parent's scope objects when you are at their children level. though the condition is not to conflict the $scope object's name with your children's $scope object's name since this will overwrite the object.